# Tkinter Trace and ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Python/programming, so please be gentle! I've been fairly good at figuring stuff out for myself (or finding answers here!) so far, but i've been struggling with this for a while now..
Using Tkinter, I want a label to print the sum of two entry fields, updating automatically after each entry input. This is where I've got to:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

root = Tk()

first_var = IntVar()
second_var = IntVar()
total_var = IntVar()

para = [0, 0]

def totalupdate(*args):
    global para
    para[0] = first_var.get()
    para[1] = second_var.get()
    newtotal = sum(para)
    total_var.set(newtotal)

first_var.trace('w', totalupdate)
second_var.trace('w', totalupdate)

first = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=first_var)
second = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=second_var)
total = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=total_var)

first.grid()
second.grid()
total.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

So, this seems to work fine within the Tk window, but it throws up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/T‌​kinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
  File "para.py", line 15, in totalupdate
    para[1] = second_var.get()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/T‌​kinter.py", line 283, in get
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

in the terminal window any time I use .get() within a trace callback function. I've tried multiple ways of getting around this to no avail. I'm sure there's a pretty simple solution, and it doesn't seem to affect the program but its bugging me! Any help much appreciated, as well as any comments concerning a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do. Many thanks!

Comment: What is the full traceback for the exception?

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
  File "para.py", line 15, in totalupdate
    para[1] = second_var.get()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 283, in get
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Next time, you want to [edit] your question and add that information. :-)

Comment: Ah ok! Cheers Martijn, will do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever your first variable changes, the trace is triggered, but the second value is still empty. An empty string is not an integer, and the exception is thrown.

In this case, I'd catch that exception and simply return, until *both* variables hold proper integers:

```
def totalupdate(*args):
    global para
    try:
        para[0] = first_var.get()
        para[1] = second_var.get()
    except ValueError:
        # one or both values are not integers
        return
    newtotal = sum(para)
    total_var.set(newtotal)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for that Martijn, you've been a great help! This site is superb...